# ElasticSearch field for sort index and wildcard query

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, indexing, lucene

I have an ID field which is a UUID that I want to use as unique sort (because created_at is not unique) and wildcard query.
Example, searching b85f9fdd will result in document with ID b85f9fdd-5557-4f70-bbd7-9a23b0485235
I have try to create this index:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "sort.field": [ "created_at", "id" ],
            "sort.order": [ "desc", "desc" ]
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "id": { "type": "wildcard", "fields": { "raw": { "type": "keyword" }}},
            "current_status": { "type": "keyword" },
            "version_rev":    { "type": "keyword" },
            "tracking_id":     { "type": "wildcard" },
            "invoice_number":  { "type": "keyword" },
            "created_at":     { "type": "date" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i got the reply:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "invalid index sort field:[id]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "invalid index sort field:[id]"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort by `id.raw` instead:

```
"settings": {
    "index": {
        "sort.field": [ "created_at", "id.raw" ],
        "sort.order": [ "desc", "desc" ]
    }
},
```